# Custom Google Map Icon with Heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, image, google-maps, heroku

I am deploying a rails site that includes an embedded google map.  I have a couple images I wanted to use as custom google map icons, but I cannot get them to display when deployed to heroku (404 error).

I know that for background images to show I use a scss file with image-url, but I can't figure out how to format the JS file for heroku to find the image.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
var wedding = 'assets/glyph-ring.png';
var weddingPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(44.192309, -82.243499);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: weddingPosition,
  map: map,
  icon: wedding
});
```

Comment: 'assets/glyph-ring.png' - Does not exist in fingerprinted filenames in production.

Comment: Why dont you just put the image on a public server and fetch it via http like this icon: 'http://cdn.com/glyph-ring.png.png' its easier.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I was able to figure it out!